# Fullcalendar: How to hook into eventAfterAllRender?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have this code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
    function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,
        {
            settings here ...
        }
        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
```

I want to run some JavaScript each time new events are loaded (and for the events loaded on the inital page load). Should I use eventAfterAllRender and how do I do it?

Comment: EventsAfterAllRender was removed in version 5. How are you loading your events into the calendar? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function allows you to call your event feed in a custom way and therefore you can run custom code before and after the request (although before the events are actually rendered).

Comment: P.s. for future reference your question is more likely to be seen quickly if you are the extra tags as I've done above - I check the main fullCalendar tag reasonably often but the specific version ones not so much - they're mainly there to help me give version-specific answers.

Comment: Alternatively if you want to do something similar _for each event_ then use the event render hooks: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks